# Elasticsearch NEST and basic Search query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I'm using NEST. When I run my query in the browser (host/logstash-2019.03.17/_search?pretty) I get the following result:

```
{
 "took" : 138,
 "timed_out" : false,
   "shards" : {
     "total" : 1,
     "successful" : 1,
     "skipped" : 0,
     "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
     "value" : 10,
     "relation" : "eq"
 },
  "max_score" : 1.0,
  "hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "logstash-2019.03.17",
    "_type" : "logevent",
    "_id" : "aa7djGkB1zvCMljS8jPd",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "@timestamp" : "2019-03-17T18:15:43.9506399Z",
      "level" : "Info",
      "message" : "Attempting to get results from ElasticSearch",
      "logger" : "App.Api.Controllers.MyController"
    }
  }, OTHER HITS IN THE SAME FORMAT
```

However, when I'm trying to query the same index using ElasticClient i get the following exception:

> Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: „Cannot
>   deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Int64' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g.
>   string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly. To fix this
>   error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string,
>   number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a
>   normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a
>   collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized
>   from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type
>   to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path
>   'hits.total.value', line 1, position 115.”

I thought NEST is capable of autodeserializing JSON correctly on condition that it is provided with a class whose properties correspond to "_source" object fields. At least this is what you can infer from [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-getting-started.html) tutorial.

Here is my POCO class follwed by the query which throws the exception:

```
public class Logevent
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Logger { get; set; }
    }


var client = new ElasticClient();

var searchResponse = client.Search<Logevent>(s => s.Index("logstash-2019.03.17").Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Level).Query("message"))));
```

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not an answer to why it can't deserialize the hits total, but `aa7djGkB1zvCMljS8jPd` is not a valid Guid.. maybe you should make your Id property a string.

Comment: @stuard Did that, yet the problem hasn't gone.

Comment: Like I said, not an answer to the problem you've having. I don't know why Nest is failing to parse the hits total (note in the error message it is saying the error is at `'hits.total.value', line 1, position 115.`)

Comment: One possibility - are the versions of Nest and ES compatible..?

Comment: Can you share your mappings?

Comment: @stuard I see that I'm having problems with the total.value. What I can't understand is  why NEST would want to deserialize the metadata and not just the _source object. Do I need to write another class to store all the metadata? They don't mention a word about that in the tutorial.

Comment: @LeBigCat Shouldn't the mappings be done by the NEST library?

Comment: @stuard I'm using Elasticsearch 7.0.0-beta1 and NEST 6.5.1

Comment: _"What I can't understand is why NEST would want to deserialize the metadata and not just the _source object"_ - because the search returns an [`ISearchResponse<T>`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/Search/Search/SearchResponse.cs) (where `T` here is `LogEvent`) and that interface contains all the metadata. I see you're using a beta version of ES, your problem could of course be related to an issue with the beta or how it's interacting with Nest 6.5.1

Comment: Because of the initial Guid issue, i thinck you didnot index your document using nest, if this is the case, check the mappings with the Poco class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using a newer version of Elasticsearch (maybe one of the 7.0.0 prereleases?) where [the `total` field is no longer just an `Int64` value](https://www.elastic.co/blog/faster-retrieval-of-top-hits-in-elasticsearch-with-block-max-wand)

```
"total" : {
     "value" : 10,
     "relation" : "eq"
}
```

NEST 6.x does not handle this, NEST 7.x will however, when it's released. For now, I would recommend using the latest Elasticsearch 6.x, currently 6.6.2.

Major versions of NEST are tied to major versions of Elasticsearch, so

- NEST 5.x -> Elasticsearch 5.x
- NEST 6.x -> Elasticsearch 6.x
- etc.

But I would recommend keeping NEST up to date on minors within a major; we maintain backwards binary compatibility within a major to help with this.

Comment: Thank you! I've installed a 6.x version and now everything works fine. I'm looking forward to working with NEST 7. Best!